# Display Coordinates using Location Manager and Location Listener

Tags: java, android

This is the code for my class.  The textviews are in the activity and my goal is just to display the latitude and longitude in the textviews. Right now, it looks like nothing is happening when I run the application.  The textviews just display "Textview".

```
public class MBTATracker extends Activity {

public LocationManager locationManager;
public LocationListener locationListener;
public double latittudenumber;
public double longitudenumber;

TextView lat;
TextView longitude;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mbta_tracker);
    lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_label);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_label);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latittudenumber = location.getLatitude();
            longitudenumber = location.getLongitude();
            lat.setText(Double.toString(latittudenumber));
            longitude.setText(Double.toString(longitudenumber));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle  extras) {

        }

         @Override
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity (intent);

        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0,locationListener);

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
               if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET

            }, 10);
            return;

        }

    } else {

    }

}


public void onRequestPermissionResult (int requestCode, String [] permissions,int [] grantResults){
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
               return;

    }

}
```

}

Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitude_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/local_mbta_list"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitude_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latitude_label"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should check permissions before you call requestLocationUpdates.  You should also requestLocationUpdates in onRequestPermissionResults if they're granted.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS system is really slow, you could get the coordinates by the network.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) is the official Android developers' guide.

In fact, to retrieve coordinates in the fastest way you could use this:

```
  Location loc;
        try {
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }catch (Exception e){
//SecurityException if permissions are not enabled
            loc = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(loc!=null){//We can use coordinates, yay!
            longitude = (float) loc.getLongitude();
            latitude = (float) loc.getLatitude();
            txtLatLng.setText(getString(R.string.latitude).concat(Float.toString(latitude)).concat(" ").concat(getString(R.string.longitude).concat(Float.toString(longitude))));
        }else{//No last location updated so we must use slow GPS method
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);}
```

[Source of this code](https://github.com/FoodAdvisorProject/FoodAdvisorAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pro/rane/foodadvisor/NewProductFragment.java)